# Implementing RSA/pkcs1_padding in Python 3.X

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, ssl, rsa

I'm trying to move my code from Python 2.7 to Python 3.5

Below is the current implementation in **Python 2.7** which uses M2Crypto

```
import M2Crypto
import hashlib
from binascii import hexlify

# Generates the signature of payload
def getSign(payload_xml):
    # SHA-1 digest of the payload
    dig = myDigest(payload_xml)
    # Loading the privateKey PEM file
    private_key = M2Crypto.RSA.load_key('privatekey')
    # Generating base 16 and encoding
    signature = hexlify(private_key.private_encrypt(dig, M2Crypto.RSA.pkcs1_padding))
    return signature

# To generate sha-1 digest of payload
def myDigest(payload):

    # This will give base 16 of SHA-1 digest
    digest_1 = hashlib.sha1(payload).hexdigest()
    return digest_1

sign = getSign(<mypayload_xml>)
```

And this is the new implementation in **Python 3.5** using pycryptodome

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from binascii import hexlify

def myDigest(payload):
    # This will give base 16 of SHA-1 digest
    digest_1 = hashlib.sha1(payload.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    return digest_1

def getSign(payload_xml):
    # SHA-1 digest of the payload
    dig = myDigest(payload_xml)
    with open('privatekey', 'r') as pvt_key:
        miPvt = pvt_key.read()
    rsa_key_obj = RSA.importKey(miPvt)
    cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsa_key_obj)
    cipher_text = cipher.encrypt(dig.encode())
    base_16_new = hexlify(cipher_text)
    return base_16_new

new_sign = getSign(<mypayload_xml>)
```

> However, for same payload, signatures are different. Can someone help
>   with the proper solution?

Comment: As far as I know, the `encrypt`- and `decrypt`-methods of the PyCryptodome `Cipher`-class only allow encryption with the public key and decryption with the private key, i.e. PyCryptodome has no 1:1 counterparts to the `private_encrypt`- and `public_decrypt`-methods of M2Crypto you use (instead PyCryptodome has the sign- and verify-methods of the `Signature`-class). In the Python 3.6 code, therfore, only the SHA1-hash of the payload is encrypted using the public key (even if the private key is applied, only the portion with the public key is used). This is pure encryption and no signing.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in my comment, [`encrypt`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/pkcs1_v1_5.html#Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5.PKCS115_Cipher.encrypt) and [`decrypt`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/pkcs1_v1_5.html#Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5.PKCS115_Cipher.decrypt) of PyCryptodome can only be used to encrypt with the *public* key and decrypt with the *private* key. PyCryptodome has no 1:1-counterpart to `private_encrypt` or `public_decrypt` of M2Crypto, which allows the encryption with the private key and the decryption with the public key. Instead PyCryptodome uses [`sign`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_v1_5.html#Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15.PKCS115_SigScheme.sign) and [`verify`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_v1_5.html#Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15.PKCS115_SigScheme.verify), which however work differently *in detail*, so that `private_encrypt` and `sign` *don't generate the same signature* (for the same key and message):

---

`sign` implements RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5 padding described in [RFC 8017, chapter 8.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2). The hash value `H` of the message is padded as follows:

```
0x00 || 0x01 || PS || 0x00 || ID || H
```

`ID` identifies the digest and is for SHA1 (see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#page-47) for other digests):

```
(0x)30 21 30 09 06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a 05 00 04 14
```

`PS` are `0xFF` fill bytes, so that the padded message has the length of the modulus.

---

The padding of `private_encrypt` differs from RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5 padding in such a way that `ID` is not added automatically. So that `sign` and `private_encrypt` generate the same signature, `ID` must be added *manually* in the context of `private_encrypt`, e.g:

```
import M2Crypto
import hashlib
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify

key = """-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"""

def getSign(payload_xml):
    dig = myDigest(payload_xml)
    private_key = M2Crypto.RSA.load_key_string(key)
    signature = hexlify(private_key.private_encrypt(unhexlify('3021300906052b0e03021a05000414' + dig.hexdigest()), M2Crypto.RSA.pkcs1_padding))
    return signature

def myDigest(payload_xml):
    digest_1 = hashlib.sha1(payload_xml)
    return digest_1 

sign = getSign(b"Hello world")
print("M2Crypto: " + sign)
```

As a site note, there is a bug in the original code: `private_encrypt` expects the data in binary format and not as hexadecimal string.

---

The corresponding PyCryptodome code could be e.g.:

```
from Crypto.Signature import pkcs1_15
from Crypto.Hash import SHA1
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

key = """-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"""

def getSign(payload_xml):
    dig = myDigest(payload_xml)
    private_key = RSA.import_key(key)
    signature = pkcs1_15.new(private_key).sign(dig)
    return signature

def myDigest(payload_xml):
    digest_1 = SHA1.new(payload_xml)
    return digest_1 

sign = getSign(b'Hello world')
print("PyCryptodome: " + sign.hex())
```

---

With the following test key (for simplicity a 512 bit key):

```
key = """-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBVQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT8wggE7AgEAAkEA2gdsVIRmg5IH0rG3
u3w+gHCZq5o4OMQIeomC1NTeHgxbkrfznv7TgWVzrHpr3HHK8IpLlG04/aBo6U5W
2umHQQIDAQABAkEAu7wulGvZFat1Xv+19BMcgl3yhCdsB70Mi+7CH98XTwjACk4T
+IYv4N53j16gce7U5fJxmGkdq83+xAyeyw8U0QIhAPIMhbtXlRS7XpkB66l5DvN1
XrKRWeB3RtvcUSf30RyFAiEA5ph7eWXbXWpIhdWMoe50yffF7pW+C5z07tzAIH6D
Ko0CIQCyveSTr917bdIxk2V/xNHxnx7LJuMEC5DcExorNanKMQIgUxHRQU1hNgjI
sXXZoKgfaHaa1jUZbmOPlNDvYYVRyS0CIB9ZZee2zubyRla4qN8PQxCJb7DiICmH
7nWP7CIvcQwB
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"""
```

both codes provide for the following message:

```
payload_xml = b'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

the following signature:

```
8324a560e6934fa1d1421b9ae37641c3b50a5c3872beecea808fbfed94151747aad69d5e083a23aa0b134d9e8c65e3a9201bb22ec28f459e605692e53965ad3b
```

*Conclusion*: It is possible to modify the M2Crypto code so that the result corresponds to the PyCryptodome code by simply adding `ID`. The other way around, however, it doesn't seem to be possible, because the PyCryptodome implementation adds `ID` automatically and this apparently can't be prevented.

Answer (score 0):

In the second snippet, you are **encrypting** the SHA-1 digest using the PKCS#1 1.5 algorithm (`Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5` module). That is not a signature.

Instead, you should use the `Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15` module of `pycryptodome`. For instance, see the example taken from [here](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_v1_5.html):

```
from Crypto.Signature import pkcs1_15
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

message = 'To be signed'
key = RSA.import_key(open('private_key.der').read())
h = SHA256.new(message)
signature = pkcs1_15.new(key).sign(h)
```